# Collapsing rows in a Dataframe into one specific row to fill missing values?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I want to collapse values in all rows into the first (or specified) row

The dataframe looks like this:

```
id     column1     column2     column3
A                  15          
B      13  
C                              10
```

I want it to look like this:

```
id     column1     column2     column3
A      13            15        10
```

Apologies if my formatting sucks, this is my first submission.

Comment: Are those empty values `NaN`s or empty strings ?

Comment: empty strings I think, I replaced 'NaN' with ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick is to use `GroupBy.first` which by default ignores NA values.

```
df[df.ne('')].groupby(np.zeros(len(df))).first()
```

---

Another option is to use `''.join` in each column, given you have empty strings in those empty slots.

```
df.astype(str).apply(''.join).to_frame().T

    id  column1  column2  column3
0.0  A     13.0     15.0     10.0
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much!